# How do I write a vector as a linear combination of other vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Write $\begin{pmatrix} 5  \\ 3 \\15 \end{pmatrix}$ as a linerar combination of the following vectors:  $u=\begin{pmatrix} 1  \\ 2 \\5 \end{pmatrix}$, $v=\begin{pmatrix} 3  \\ -4 \\-1 \end{pmatrix}$, $w=\begin{pmatrix} -1  \\ 1 \\1 \end{pmatrix}$.

My attempt:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3& -1 & 5\\
2 & -4 & 1& 3\\
5&-1&1&15\\
 \end{bmatrix}\sim\to\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0& 0 & 3\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
0&0&1&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Obviously I skipped a lot of reduction steps, because it's a pain to type matrices here, but I was wondering if I even did the right thing.

Comment: Looks good, just make sure you finish it off. Your conclusion is...?

Comment: $x_1=3$,$x_2=1$,and$x_3=1$?

Comment: If $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the constants multiplying $u,v,w$ (respectively) to get $(5,3,15)$, then YES.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So...you've done the hard part, now finish it off:

$$c_1\begin{pmatrix} 1  \\ 2 \\5 \end{pmatrix} + c_2 \begin{pmatrix} 3  \\ -4 \\-1 \end{pmatrix}+ c_3\begin{pmatrix} -1  \\ 1 \\1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 5  \\ 3 \\15 \end{pmatrix}$$

So what have you found to be $c_1, c_2, c_3$?

Fill in the correct values for each constant, and you're done!

Comment: Note, just substitute into the equation in my answer the values $x_1 = 3 = c_1, \;x_2 =1 = c_2,\;x_3 = 1 = c_3$, given your conclusion in your comment above about the values of $x_1, x_2, x_3$, and you'll have expressed the vector $[5, 3, 15]^T$ as a linear combination of u, v, w.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this problem up as linear system of 3 equations

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 3 \\ 15 \end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 &-1 \\ 2 & -4 & 1 \\ 5 & -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma \end{pmatrix} $$

You do this by arranging the basis vectors as columns to the coefficient matrix.